# How to prevent bluetooth from being turned on in public ipad

Tags: ios, security, ipad

A professional photographer friend of mine shoots kids' competitive events and sells the images right on the spot. potential customers can view the images on the handful of ipads (5th gen, iOS v16.2) he has sitting at his table. recently he experienced an incident where a person turned on bluetooth on one of those ipads and was able to steal the images via AirDrop feature. is there way to allow only specific user(s) to toggle bluetooth feature, which would prevent customers from turning bluetooth on, while my friend can still use it at will? thank you!

Comment: Maybe a couple of possibilities here: https://flylib.com/books/en/4.395.1.118/1/

Comment: Use the Apple Configurator tool to install a profile that denies access to Bluetooth settings. You can also turn off airdrop. Supervising the device will require it to be erased and set up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Apple Configurator 2 app to configure and install a profile on the device to lock out those settings.
https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator

A great free tool for building profiles for devices is iMazing Profile Editor.
https://imazing.com/profile-editor

Here's where that setting is located in the iMazing Profile Editor:
Go to Restrictions on left panel, then click add payload on right panel.  On General Tab, scroll down and deselect "Allow modifying Bluetooth settings". Go to AirDrop tab, deselect "Allow AirDrop".  Then go to File>Save As and save the configuration profile in a location you can easily access.  It will be a .mobileconfig file.  Now use the Configurator of your choice to apply it to your devices.

They have an iMazing Configurator program that can apply profiles to a device that's a bit friendlier than Apple Configurator, but it is not free.
https://imazing.com/configurator

In either case, you need a Mac computer to run the configurator program to assign the profile if doing it from a computer.  You can also do this using a Mobile Device Management cloud platform.  Most MDM platforms can apply that .mobileconfig file/policy to your devices, but they also typically have built-in policy options that will let you do this without needing to build a .mobileconfig file first.  For just a few devices, there are several options that would be free to use, even for business purposes.  Below are some options worth considering.

https://www.miradore.com/mdm/free

https://jumpcloud.com/platform/cloud-device-management

https://www.manageengine.com/mobile-device-management/free-mobile-device-management-software.html